# how to remove list-divider when remove the li in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a set of group list(li). If i going to delete all "li" in  a group i want to remove that list-divider also. I mean if there are 3 "li" after a list-divider, when i remove "li" one by one, at last when i remove the last "li". I want to remove that list-divider also.

Live Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/69cqA/15/

In the above example i have 3 groups, when i remove groupBdel_ "li". I want to remove the list-divider of groupB also.

Like that when i remove all "li" in groupAdel_, I want to remove the list-divider "groupA"

Kindly give me a solution to remove list-divider with li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle to achieve your result

http://jsfiddle.net/69cqA/34/

Comment: How to check that collapsible is empty or not once we remove all the "li" inside the collapsible list.

Comment: just add an id attribute to ul tag and add the following code to all click events if($("#list li").length==0){
        alert('all removed from collapsible');
    }

Comment: is it possible to update that fiddle? Another thing in the existing code, if i click the first "li" in the "groupA", then list-divider removed, under other "li" are still remaining. I want to remove that list-divider when i remove the whole "li" in that group. Please check.